# How can I convert connection data lines to block of schemes using Perl?

Tags: perl, graph

I'm looking for a way to convert signals connections to a simple scheme or graph.

Let's say I have 2 components with 2 line/signals around them:

```
component A:
 input - S1
 output - S2

component B: 
 input - S2
 output - S1
```

This will be the input data file, and the output will be a scheme that shows it as 2 blocks with connecting lines around them or a illustration graph.

I'm wondering if an implementation of that exists in Perl's world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like the [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) graph generator.

It's written in C, but there is a Perl interface: [GraphViz](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GraphViz).

Example:

```
use GraphViz;
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);

my $g = GraphViz->new;
$g->add_node('componentA');
$g->add_node('componentB');
$g->add_edge('componentB' => 'componentA', label => 'S1');
$g->add_edge('componentA' => 'componentB', label => 'S2');

write_file('out.png', $g->as_png);
```

You could load your input data and keep track of component connections via a hash on the signal number, then call `add_edge` for each one.

Output:

[graphviz output http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2624/outd.png](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2624/outd.png)

(labels are optional).

Comment: I think this might be good to try, but still after over look at the GraphViz, I'm wondering how can I make a massive data connections without losing its readability. The final purpose is to map a CPU architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Cf. [Graph::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph-Easy) and [GraphViz](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GraphViz).