# Options to create editable graph or scheme with Perl?

Tags: perl, graphics

I'm searching for a way to create complex/simple graph using Perl.
The known modules/applications I've checked are: [GraphViz](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GraphViz/), [Graph-Easy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph-Easy/), [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) etc.
Each way I walked, new problems appeared.

If my need is to create graph dependencies that

- can be edited live
- have a directed compass mode
- work fine and are readable with massive data use
- can be used through the terminal to convert from input format ([GDL](http://www.aisee.com/gdl/) etc.) to output format (PNG, BMP, HTML etc.) –

what are the various applications that can handle all of these requests?

This question is a follow-up of [How can I convert connection data lines to block of schemes using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758957).

Thanks,

YoDar.

Comment: What do you mean by "new problems appear"?  Perhaps the problems are not with the packages you are trying, but something else.

Comment: "new problems appear" means that I cant combine in one module/application all the needs I wrote. Each module/application has it's benefits and disadvantage. Again, I'm searching for some pure graphic module/application to satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an overkill for your application, but you might also want to look into [PerlMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php).